# Launchpad PPA: " dh_install: warning: Cannot find (any matches for) "=>" (tried in ., debian/tmp)" while building package with dh-exec

Tags: package-management, ppa, packaging, launchpad

I'm working on moving some of my packaging routines into CI workflows to save myself some time when releasing new versions of my app. However, I've been running into a weird issue with Launchpad that I've never seen before. For my data package (which contains a bunch of Lua scripts and other text resources), I use `dh-exec` with an `install` script to move all of the files into the binary package. This has worked flawlessly on my machine for years, but as soon as I started building and uploading from the CI server, Launchpad buildd started reporting this error for every file in the `install` script:

```
dh_install: warning: Cannot find (any matches for) "=>" (tried in ., debian/tmp)
```

I've never seen this on my system before, and I'm using the exact same debian folder on CI as I use locally. The error suggests that `=>` is being interpreted as the file name, but this shouldn't be possible as `=>` is part of the syntax of the `install` file, and there's no extra spaces between the tokens. The only thing I could think of is that the generator script I use to make the `install` file isn't working right, but it appears to match previous working `install` scripts from earlier. I tried moving my build target from Bionic to Focal (just in case this was an issue, and also because I dropped Bionic in the latest version), but this didn't work. I also tried switching the path from `/usr/share/...` to `debian/craftos-pc-data/usr/share/...`, and this allowed it to build, but it ended up placing files in `/debian` on installed systems! (I had to emergency pull that package real quick.)

The only difference between my system and the CI server is that CI generates the changelog and install files automatically every time, and the files are hosted on GitHub instead of locally. I also use Arch Linux to build packages myself these days, but I used to use Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL as well. (I did create the repo on an NTFS drive - hopefully there's no permission problems there? I know that `install` requires executable privileges, but this doesn't appear to be a problem, as it's still executing the script.)

Here's what my `install` file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env dh-exec
hdfont.bmp => /usr/share/craftos/hdfont.bmp
debug/console.lua => /usr/share/craftos/debug/console.lua
debug/showfile.lua => /usr/share/craftos/debug/showfile.lua
debug/profiler.lua => /usr/share/craftos/debug/profiler.lua
debug/releasenotes.lua => /usr/share/craftos/debug/releasenotes.lua
...
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue to appear? If you need them, here are [the control file archive](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejackmacwindows/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcefiles/craftos-pc-data/2.7.1-1/craftos-pc-data_2.7.1-1.debian.tar.xz), [the complete build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/621302609/buildlog_ubuntu-focal-amd64.craftos-pc-data_2.7.1-1_BUILDING.txt.gz), and the build scripts: [workflow](https://github.com/MCJack123/craftos2-rom/blob/master/.github/workflows/release.yml), [build & upload script called from workflow](https://github.com/MCJack123/craftos2-release-resources/blob/master/ubuntu/debian_craftos-pc-data/buildall.sh).

**UPDATE:** I managed to get it to work by moving `debian/install` to `debian/craftos-pc-data.install`. However, I'd appreciate to understand why just `install` used to work, but doesn't work anymore - I can't find any information from Debian about what might have changed to make this happen.

Comment: Hmm, did you see dh_install limitations section in the manual page? https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_install.1.en.html

Comment: @Quasímodo I did, and my package does all of those.

Answer (score 1):

If the Launchpad build used [exactly this `.debian` archive](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejackmacwindows/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcefiles/craftos-pc-data/2.7.1-1/craftos-pc-data_2.7.1-1.debian.tar.xz), then the problem comes from the missing executable bit on `debian/install`:

```
$ tar tvf craftos-pc-data_2.7.1-1.debian.tar.xz debian/install
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           16269 2022-09-01 22:44 debian/install
```

Your [latest archive](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejackmacwindows/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcefiles/craftos-pc-data/2.7.1-4/craftos-pc-data_2.7.1-4.debian.tar.xz) has the executable bit set:

```
$ tar tvf craftos-pc-data_2.7.1-4.debian.tar.xz debian/craftos-pc-data.install
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0           16269 2022-09-01 23:53 debian/craftos-pc-data.install
```

Since you’re not renaming any of the files you install, you don’t actually need `dh-exec`; if you change your build script so that the `install` file looks like

```
hdfont.bmp usr/share/craftos/
debug/console.lua usr/share/craftos/debug/
debug/showfile.lua /usr/share/craftos/debug/
…
```

*i.e.* file names followed by their target path, you could drop the build dependency on `dh-exec` entirely.

You could even handle directories with a single entry, reducing your `install` file to:

```
bios.lua usr/share/craftos/
hdfont.bmp usr/share/craftos/
debug usr/share/craftos/
rom usr/share/craftos/
```

or even

```
bios.lua hdfont.bmp debug rom use/share/craftos/
```